# What's wrong with my PATCH request body in Swagger?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to implement PATCH operation for my WebAPI. I'm trying to update using PATCH.

My controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPatch("update/{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateSite(int id, [FromBody]JsonPatchDocument<Site> sitePatch)
```

This is my Site class:

```
public class Site
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string site_name { get; set; }
}
```

This is what I'm putting in my request body in Swagger:

```
{
  "op": "replace",
  "path": "site_name",
  "value": "FOOO"
}
// I have also tried with: "path": "/site_name"
```

When the code hits the controller, I see the sitePatch variable is always empty, it has 0 Operations. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Do you check the model state in the controller's action?

Comment: From [JsonPatchDocumentConverter](https://github.com/aspnet/JsonPatch/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch/Converters/JsonPatchDocumentConverter.cs#L37), the first element has to be a array. Try to encasulapte the json with `[...]`.

Answer (score 1):

A JSON Patch document ([`JsonPatchDocument<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-5.0#json-patch-example)) has an *array* of operation object(s).

You do have a valid operation object but it is not in an array, so it is not being deserialised correctly.

The below JSON should populate `sitePatch` as expected:

```json
[
    {
      "op": "replace",
      "path": "site_name",
      "value": "FOOO"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've totally missed this:

```
services
.AddControllersWithViews()
.AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Then it works.